# IBM Analytics Workspace - Report/Query data download using REST API

Tags: c#, powershell, cognos-11

Is there a possibility to download data from IBM Analytics Workspace report/query using REST API ?
I would like to download sych data directly to the program variable using PowerShell/C#.
I have been looking for the answer online for a while but I cannot find satisfying answer leaving alone some code examples.

I would be grateful to get some code examples or links to such.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe `Invoke-RestMethod` to `ConvertTo-Json` and then pipe to `Out-File`. That's a typical workflow for interacting with APIs, if you want to download data to disk.

Presumably there's some authentication needed and presumably you have an API key. So your script would look something like

```
$Headers = @{
    api_key = $MyApiKey
}
$Uri = 'https://cloud.ibm.com/some_service/some_resource_type'
$Result = Invoke-RestMethod $Uri -Headers $Headers
$Result | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File my_data.json
```

Without knowing what API you want to query, no-one can give you a more specific example.

A better way to submit a question would be "How can I download data with powershell from the Foo API - the docs for this endpoint are at ibm.com/api_docs/how_to_foo"

Comment: Thank you for the advice !
I am interested in Mashup Service and SOAP or REST API.
The IBM documentation is here:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.0.0?topic=guide-overview-mashup-service

Comment: Oh sweet Jesus they don't support REST auth... the docs state to web scrape to log on... https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.0.0?topic=off-logging-using-mashup-service-authentication-methods#rest_logon_mash . It's doable in Powershell, but it needs more time than I can give you :-(

Comment: You'll want to work with REST - it has supplanted SOAP because it's much easier to work with.